# Getting attribute error : module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'canvas'

Tags: django, python-3.x, matplotlib, django-templates, attributeerror

```
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))

    sns.heatmap(conf_matrix, annot=True, fmt="d");
    plt.title("Confusion matrix")
    plt.ylabel('True class')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted class')

    html_fig = mpld3.fig_to_html(plt,template_type='general')
    plt.close(plt)
```

Code in HTML file to fetch the image :

```
    <div id="fig_container">
    {{ div_figure|safe }}
</div>
```

Using latest versions of `Python` and `Django`. On executing the attribute error is displayed

> module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'canvas'

I am new to it and unable to resolve the error. Please help!!!

Comment: Please add a few lines more context around that code snippet, particularly your import of pyplot and your use of canvas.

Comment: It seems you call `mpld3.fig_to_html(matplotlib.pyplot)` which is not correct. That function would probably expect a figure as input, `fig = plt.figure(); ....; mpld3.fig_to_html(fig)`

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue. You probably have solved the problem by now, but anyway I'm posting an answer.

The main point here is that mpld3 works with the *fig* object used in matplotlib. Like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
html_fig = mpld3.fig_to_html(fig)
```

So for your solution you should get the figure object from your seaborn plot. It can be done either this way (whatch the ax argument):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.heatmap(conf_matrix, annot=True, fmt="d", ax=ax)
html_fig = mpld3.fig_to_html(fig)
```

Or this way:

```
fig = sns.heatmap(conf_matrix, annot=True, fmt="d").get_figure()
html_fig = mpld3.fig_to_html(fig)
```

If you want to include seaborn plots and matplotlib in general in django projects using mpld3 I'd recommend to view [*this question*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49352276/why-is-this-plot-not-displaying-in-template-but-works-fine-if-url-is-viewed-dire)